# How can I improve the efficiency of my algorithm, while I use two loops inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, matrix

Dear experienced friends, I proposed a method to solve an algorithm problem. However, I found my method becomes **very time-consuming** when the data size grows. May I ask is there any better way to solve this problem? Is it possible to use matrix manipulation?

**The question**:

- Suppose we have 1 `score-matrix` and 3 `value-matrix`.
- Each of them is a `square matrix` with the same size `(N*N)`.
- The element in `score-matrix` means the `weights` between two entities. For example, `S12` means the score between `entity 1` and `entity 2`. (Weights are only meaningful when greater than 0.)
- The element in `value-matrix` means the `values` between two entities. For example, `V12` means the value between `entity 1` and `entity 2`. Since we have 3 `value-matrix`, we have 3 different `V12`.

**The target is**: I want to multiply the `values` with the corresponding `weights`, so that I can finally output a `(Nx3)` matrix.

My solutions: I solved this problem as follows. However, I use two for-loops here, which makes my program become very **time-consuming**. (e.g. When `N` is big or `3` becomes `100`) May I ask is there any way to improve this code? Any suggestions or hints would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
# generate sample data
import numpy as np
score_mat = np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=(2,2))
value_mat = np.random.randn(3,2,2)

# solve problem
# init the output info
output = np.zeros((2, 3))

# update the output info
for entity_1 in range(2):

    # consider meaningful score
    entity_others_list = np.where(score_mat[entity_1,:]>0)[0].tolist()

    # iterate every other entity
    for entity_2 in entity_others_list:

        vec = value_mat[:,entity_1,entity_2].copy()

        vec *= score_mat[entity_1,entity_2]

        output[entity_1] += vec
```

Comment: Maybe you can split the values and scores into matrices, then use matrix multiplication (numpy)?

Comment: And could you skip the np.where? It is cheaper to multiply by zero than select non-zero values

Comment: Hi @Stefan. Thank you for your comments. I consider your advice, but even I do not use the np.where, I still need to iterate all the column indexes. While not all of them are non-zero. I guess np.where limits the range and improves the efficiency. Please let me know if anything I make is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate them manually, just multiply `score_mat` by `value_mat`, then call `sum` on `axis=2`, again call `sum` on `axis=1`.

As you have mentioned that the `score` will make sense only if it is greater than zero, if that's the case, you can first replace non-positive values by 1, since multiplying something by 1 remains intact:

```py
>>> score_mat[score_mat<=0] = 1
>>> (score_mat*value_mat).sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)
array([-0.58826032, -3.08093186, 10.47858256])
```

Break-down:

```py
# This is what the randomly generated numpy arrays look like:
>>> score_mat
array([[3, 3],
       [1, 3]])
>>> value_mat
array([[[ 0.81935985,  0.92228075],
        [ 1.07754964, -2.29691059]],
       [[ 0.12355602, -0.36182607],
        [ 0.49918847, -0.95510339]],
       [[ 2.43514089,  1.17296263],
        [-0.81233976,  0.15553725]]])

# When you multiply the matcrices, each inner matrices in value_mat will be multiplied
# element-wise by score_mat
>>> score_mat*value_mat
array([[[ 2.45807955,  2.76684225],
        [ 1.07754964, -6.89073177]],
       [[ 0.37066806, -1.08547821],
        [ 0.49918847, -2.86531018]],
       [[ 7.30542266,  3.51888789],
        [-0.81233976,  0.46661176]]])

# Now calling sum on axis=2, will give the sum of each rows in the inner-most matrices
>>> (score_mat*value_mat).sum(axis=2)
array([[ 5.22492181, -5.81318213],
       [-0.71481015, -2.36612171],
       [10.82431055, -0.34572799]])

# Finally calling sum on axis=1, will again sum the row values
>>> (score_mat*value_mat).sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)
array([-0.58826032, -3.08093186, 10.47858256])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just try your code and compare it with my outputs. However, I find it turns `False`. But what you mention is very instructive. I am trying to understand each step and implement it on mine. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a small sample from the actual data along with the expected output for it, instead of using random numbers. The code I have added performs exactly what you have mentioned in the question, there is some explanation for each parts as well

Comment: Hi @ThePyGuy, the `output` in my code is the expected output. And I have verified it by hand. My actual data is much bigger than the sample one, where `N` is 2000 and the number of `value-matrix` is 21. So I am trying to find a more efficient way to solve it.

Comment: @NickChen, why the output in your code has `2X3` dimension? Shouldn't it be `1X3` for 3 values array? One for each value array.

Comment: It's my bad! What I show in the picture is one row of the outputs. (I just updated it, sorry for the misleading) Because we have two entities, so the output should be `(2x3)`, where each row represents the corresponding aggregated value of entity.

Comment: Okay, try this: `(score_mat*value_mat).sum(axis=-1).T`

Comment: WOW! WOW! You perfectly solve this problem! And the only thing is `score_mat[score_mat<=0]` should be `0`, because we want to discard the meaningless scores. Thank you SO MUCH, @ThePyGuy!